# Hotkey to find syntax warnings in Emacs js2-mode?

Tags: javascript, emacs, syntax-highlighting, syntax-error, js2-mode

I've got like 10,000 lines of JS and there's a missing bracket somewhere in there. js2-mode for emacs is supposed to highlight possible syntax errors, but it would still be incredibly time-consuming to look through all 10,000 lines and try to find the one little bracket that is highlighted. Can someone tell me if there is a hotkey that I can use to jump to the next syntax warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I can see from js2 source code, there is `js2-next-error` function that should move to next error. It's bound to `` C-c C-` `` by default

Comment: hmm, I do see that in the source, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. I just hit C-c and then when I hit C-`, nothing happens. It doesn't even enter that into the command.

Comment: You should also be able to access it from the main menu. And if all else fails, there's `M-x js2-next-error` and ability to rebind the key.

Comment: Well thanks, that worked. The only problem was that it said there were no errors. I guess it must not be able to detect whatever the problem was. Debugging this is going to be interesting, lol.

Comment: I just tried it on simple source file with error, and everything worked fine... I have js2-mode version 20090727...

Comment: hey yeah, I just found the error, it wasn't in the source files that I was looking in, it was in one in a different place that was getting called from them